# How to display greek letter in R plot when the letter is supplied as a string

Tags: r

I want to display Greek letters in R plot, where the letters are data frame names. For example, assume I have

```
dataframe <- read.table("input.dat");
cnames <- colnames(dataframe);
# asssume cnames[1] = "alpha[1]" cnames[2] = "alpha[2]"
```

I want to plot alpha[1] ~ alpha[2] with alpha being displayed as greek letter instead of strings i.e sth. like

```
plot(as.formula(paste(cnames[1],"~",cnames[2])), xlab=expression(cnames[1]) ......)
```

However, this doesn't work and I cannot google a solution. Does anyone know how to do that? This example seems trivial but in my real dataset, I have many columns and I need to plot some randomly chosen variables.

Many thanks

Answer (score 6):

Does this work for you?

```
x = "alpha[1]"
plot(1,1, t="n", xlab=parse(text=x))
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's call the dataframe something other than "dataframe", perhaps "dfrm". From context I am guessing you want column names rather than the name of the dataframe:

```
dfrm <-
structure(list(`alpha[1]` = 1:10, `alpha[2]` = c(10L, 9L, 8L, 
7L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 1L)), .Names = c("alpha[1]", "alpha[2]"
), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")

plot(dfrm[,1],dfrm[,2], 
         xlab=parse(text=names(dfrm)[1]), ylab=parse(text=names(dfrm)[2]) )
```

If you absolutely need to have the names used to build the formula , it's not easy but it can be done:

```
 form <-as.formula(paste(deparse(as.name(names(dfrm)[1]), backtick=T), 
                         "~",
                         deparse(as.name(names(dfrm)[2]), backtick=T) 
                )     )  
form
# `alpha[1]` ~ `alpha[2]`

 plot(form, 
      xlab=parse(text=names(dfrm)[1]), 
      ylab=parse(text=names(dfrm)[2]) ,
      data=dfrm)
```